# Swipe.js and jQuery Mobile slider flashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-webkit

Using jQueryMobile and Swipe.js I have the following code working almost perfectly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#item-1').one('pageshow', function(){
    window.slider = 
        Swipe(document.getElementById('slider-1'),{
            callback: function(pos) {
                var i = bullets0.length;
                while (i--) {
                    bullets0[i].className = ' ';
                }
                bullets0[pos].className = 'on';
            }
        });
    var bullets0 = document.getElementById('position-slider-1').getElementsByTagName('li');
});

    jQuery('#item-2').one('pageshow', function(){
    window.slider = 
        Swipe(document.getElementById('slider-2'),{
            callback: function(pos) {
                var i = bullets1.length;
                while (i--) {
                    bullets1[i].className = ' ';
                }
                bullets1[pos].className = 'on';
            }
        });
    var bullets1 = document.getElementById('position-slider-2').getElementsByTagName('li');
});
```

The problem is that the slider flashes for a second (probably while creating / loading it). I've tried calling it using other events with no luck.

I have to mention that I have multiple slides and they are generated dynamically with PHP... that's why I ended up coding it like this (I dont know how many slides per slider or how many sliders there are going to be).

Any help is appreciated.